# Updating symfony2 libs?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.0

I have tested symfony and started with 2.0 now the new 2.0.1 version it out and I want to update. Is there an easy way to update the sources?

In Zend it is basically replacing the Zend folder with new libs. Maybe I can use an script like `php bin/vendors install` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the instructions on [this post:](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-2-0-1-released)

> If you already have a project based on the Symfony Standard Edition
>   2.0.0, you can easily upgrade to 2.0.1 by getting the new deps and
>   deps.lock files.
>
> Then, run the vendors script:
>
> $ ./bin/vendors install
>
> And don't forget to clear your cache:
>
> $ php ./app/console cache:clear

Here are the files:

- [deps](https://raw.github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/v2.0.1/deps)
- [deps.lock](https://raw.github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/v2.0.1/deps.lock)